# Mean.js whole page does not refresh after username login

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm using mean.js.

I hope I'm giving you all the information you need to help, but I am stuck on something.

My main layout.server.view.html document has a number of data-ng-include statements loading various 'widgets' like a sidebar.  Each of these widgets has its own controller.

When I hit the login page and I log in to my app with facebook all of the widgets load and their controllers are executed.

When I log in with a username, none of the controllers are executed.

I've added console.log statements so I can show you what I mean...

When I login with facebook I get the following output:

---

```
2015-05-23 11:03:08.834 Navigated to http://localhost:3001/
2015-05-23 11:03:08.835 body.client.controller.js:5 body
2015-05-23 11:03:08.955 theme.client.controller.js:5 theme
2015-05-23 11:03:08.975 brand.client.controller.js:5 brand
2015-05-23 11:03:08.990 sidebar.client.controller.js:5 sidebar
2015-05-23 11:03:08.996 content-header.client.controller.js:5 content-header
2015-05-23 11:03:09.001 content-footer.client.controller.js:5 content-footer
2015-05-23 11:03:09.005 content-nav.client.controller.js:5 content-nav
2015-05-23 11:03:09.009 home.client.controller.js:7 home
```

---

When I log in with the username I get:

---

```
2015-05-23 11:05:01.376 home.client.controller.js:7 home
2015-05-23 11:05:01.377 home.client.controller.js:15 sidebar not loaded
```

---

I'm not getting the 'Navigated to' statement at the top.  So even though I am clearly going to the new page, I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meanjs/QrC5bCIWtR4

I had to go into the authentication.client.controller.js and replace the $location.path() references with $window.location.href =

Now the page reloads completely and all is well with the world.